# OCaml object instance variable resolution

Tags: class, object, ocaml

I was bit by this

```
class root = object

  val bars = "123"

end

class derived bars = object

  inherit root as super

  method speak =
    print_endline bars

end

let () =
  let a = new derived "hello" in
  a#speak
```

which surprisingly printed "123" instead of "hello".

1) Does this mean that instance variables are resolved by looking at the root most class first?

2) Assuming 1, is it possible to make sure that instance variables are resolved starting from current class upward to parent class? (I doubt this is possible because "its just how objects work in OCaml")

3) Are there compiler warning to prevent, warn about this

Comment: warning 27 helps a bit here, by stating that `bars` is unused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is just a variation of

```
let f bars =
  let bars = "123" in
  print_endline bars
```

The second value `bars` hides the first one. The `inherit root` is expanded as `val bars = "123"` and hides your `bars` value.

What you can do to override `bars` is

```
class derived x = object
  inherit root as super
  val bars = x
  method speak =
    print_endline bars
end
```